# What is the right way to identify bottlenecks in map/reduce jobs?

Tags: hadoop

In normal java development, if I want to improve the performance of an application my usual procedure would be to run the program with a profiler attached, or alternatively embed within the application a collection of instrumentation marks.  In either case, the immediate goal is to identify the hot spot of the application, and subsequently to be able to measure the effect of the changes that I make.

What is the correct analog when the application is a map/reduce job running in a hadoop cluster?

What options are available for collecting performance data when jobs appear to be running more slowly than you would predict from running equivalent logic in your development sandbox?

Answer (score 2):

### Map/Reduce Framework

Watch the Job in the **Job-Tracker**. Here you will see how long the mappers and reducers take. A common example would be if you do **too much work in the reducers**. In that case you will notice that the mappers finish quite soon while the reducers take forever.
It might also be interesting to see if all your mappers take a similar amount of time. Maybe the job is held up by a few slow tasks? This could indicate a **hardware defect** in the cluster (in which case speculative execution could be the answer) or the **workload is not distributed evenly** enough.

### The Operating System

Watch the nodes (either with something simple as top or with monitoring such as **munin** or **ganglia**) to see if your job is **cpu bound** or **io bound**. If for example your reduce phase is io bound you can increase the number of reducers you use.
Something else you might detect here is when your **tasks are using to much memory**. If the tasktrackers do not have enough RAM increasing the number of tasks per node might actually hurt performance. A monitor system might highlight the resulting **swapping**.

### The Single Tasks

You can **run a Mapper/Reducers in isolation** for profiling. In this case you can use all the tools you already know.
If you think the performance problem appears only when the job is executed in the cluster you can measure the time of relevant portions of the code with `System.nanoTime()` and use **System.outs** to output some rough performance numbers.
Of course there is also the option of adding JVM-Parameters to the child JVMs and **connecting a profiler remotely**.